# Trouble retrieving value from a list inside a Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, pycord, openai-api

I am developing a Discord bot in Python with *py-cord* and I have implemented the OpenAI API to allow users to query the AI and modify the different weights and biases.

I am trying to make the weights specific to each guild, so people in one server can have different settings to someone in a different server. To achieve this, I am trying to use a dictionary where the guild id is the key and the weights are in a list as the values, but I keep getting KeyError exceptions.

```
import os
import discord
import openai
import re
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from gtts import gTTS
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

bot = discord.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.default())

guilds = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.temp = 1
    bot.topp = 0.5
    bot.freqpen = 0.3
    bot.prespen = 0.3
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('logged in as {0.user} at'.format(bot), x, "\n")

class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label=f"Temperature. Current: {bot.temp}"))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label=f"Frequency Penalty. Current: {bot.freqpen}"))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label=f"Presence Penalty. Current: {bot.prespen}"))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label=f"Top P. Current: {bot.topp}"))

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        guilds[f'{bot.id}'] = [self.children[0].value, self.children[1].value, self.children[2].value, self.children[3].value]
        embed = discord.Embed(title="New GPT-3 weights and biases", color=0xFF5733)
        embed.add_field(name=f"Temperature: {bot.temp}", value="Controls randomness: Lowering results in less random completions. I recommend not going higher than 1.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"Frequency Penalty: {bot.freqpen}", value="How much to penalize new tokens based on their existing frequency in the text so far. ", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"Presence Penalty: {bot.prespen}", value="How much to penalize new tokens based on whether they appear in the text so far. Increases the model's likelihood to talk about new topics. Will not function above 2.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"Top P: {bot.topp}", value="Controls diversity via nucleus sampling: 0.5 means half of all likelihood-weighted options are considered. Will not function above 1.", inline=False)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embeds=[embed])

@bot.slash_command(description="Change the GPT-3 weights and biases")
async def setvalues(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    bot.id = ctx.guild.id
    modal = MyModal(title="Modify GPT-3 weights")
    await ctx.send_modal(modal)

bot.run('token')
```

This creates a modal for users to input the values they want and then sends those values in a list to the dictionary called guilds with the key being `bot.id`. However, when I run a command I created to test pulling a value from the list, I get a KeyError exception. The command I run to check is:

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def dictionarytest(ctx):
    await ctx.respond(f'{guilds[bot.id][1]}')
```

The error I get is

> Ignoring exception in command dictionarytest: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/liam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py",
> line 127, in wrapped
> ret = await coro(arg)   File "/home/liam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py",
> line 911, in _invoke
> await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)   File "/home/liam/PycharmProjects/DiscordBot/maintest.py", line 76, in
> dictionarytest
> await ctx.respond(f'{str(guilds[bot.id][1])}') KeyError: 545151014702022656
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/liam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line
> 1009, in invoke_application_command
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "/home/liam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py",
> line 359, in invoke
> await injected(ctx)   File "/home/liam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py",
> line 135, in wrapped
> raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command
> raised an exception: KeyError: 545151014702022656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can't see the data associated with your app, it's hard to know for sure, but I see something suspicious that I think may be your problem. The error you are getting is pretty self-explanatory.  When executing this line:

```
await ctx.respond(f'{guilds[bot.id][1]}')
```

the error message is telling you that there isn't any key `bot.id` in the `guilds` dict, and `bot.id` has the value `545151014702022656`. So in this case, the key is an ***integer***.

The only place you add values to the `guild` dict is this line:

```
guilds[f'{bot.id}'] = [self.children[0].value, self.children[1].value, self.children[2].value, self.children[3].value]
```

Here, you are adding a value to the `guilds` dict with a key that is a ***string***. I bet that's your problem. The integer `545151014702022656` and the string `"545151014702022656"` aren't the same thing. You fail to match the keys you have added to `guilds`, because you're adding ***string*** keys, but looking for ***integer*** keys.  So I bet all you have to do to fix your code is change the above line to:

```
guilds[bot.id] = [self.children[0].value, self.children[1].value, self.children[2].value, self.children[3].value]
```